# Query firebase data by timestamp month

Tags: firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

So i have my records in firebase cloud firestore like this :

```
[  
   {  
      "category":"drinks",
      "expensetype":"card",
      "id":"5c673c4d-0a7f-9bb4-75e6-e71c47aa8d1d",
      "name":"JJ",
      "note":"YY",
      "price":57,
      "timestamp":"2017-11-30T22:44:43+05:30"
   },
   {  
      "category":"drinks",
      "expensetype":"card",
      "id":"85731878-eaed-2740-6802-e35e7758270b",
      "name":"VV",
      "note":"TTT",
      "price":40,
      "timestamp":"2017-12-30T22:41:13+05:30"
   }
]
```

I want to query data with the timestamp and get data that belongs to a particular month or date.

For example if I click a particular month (say March) in my calendar, I want only the data of that particular month in my results. How can i do that?

I have saved the date using 
`firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`

Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit :

This is how I form my query

```
var spendsRef = this.db.collection('spend', ref => ref.where("timestamp", ">", "12-12-2017"));

this.items = spendsRef.valueChanges();
```

But it still returns me all the data in Database

Answer :

```
var todayDate = new Date("Tue Jan 02 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)") // Any date in string
var spendsRef = this.db.collection('spend', ref => ref.where("timestamp", ">", todayDate));
this.items = spendsRef.valueChanges();
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using two relative operators, you can determine the precise range of documents returned by the query:

```
ref.where("timestamp", ">=", "2017-11").where("timestamp", "<", "2017-12")
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. Do u have any working example?

Comment: The same logic: create two date values, one for the start of the month you want to capture, one for the start of the month after. Then you do a range search as in my example, but with those dates instead of strings. If you tell us what platform you are targeting, I might be able to give you the code snippets for that platform.

Comment: Let me assume that i will need only the start from date and i'm doing this in my code

`var spendsRef = this.db.collection('spend', ref => ref.where("timestamp", ">", "12-12-2017"));

this.items = spendsRef.valueChanges();`

But it doesn't work. It brings all the data in my DB

I have updated my question now. I am working on JavaScript by the way

Comment: I'm using Ionic framework with JavaScript (TypeScript) with Angular 4. Firebase 4.8.0 and Angularfire2

Comment: Ok. I got it working. My angular moment plugin was returning as string and i was not able to get it in the exact date format of JavaScript `new Date()` function. I took date from JavaScript `new Date()` function and parsed it from string to date again and it worked. Thanks for your help. 

I have updated my new code in question for anyone searching for the answer

Comment: What you gave was the right solution that I was searching for. I will accept this as answer. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

This is the android way

`Query query = mFirestore.collection("rootcollection").whereEqualTo("month", 3);`

you can further sort the result by timestamp

```
Query query = mFirestore.collection("rootcollection")
    .orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
    .whereEqualTo("month", 3);
```

Comment: Sorry. I have updated my question now. I will not have any month fields in my database. I will only have the timestamp. I want to get the data of a particular month only with the timestamp. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I am working with node.js and storing one parameter as `new Date(new Date().toUTCString())`.

Now, I fetch the same data, do some processing over it and use the parameter as `new Date(<param received in fetch>)` in where query to get the same record amongst many records.

Thank you @Syed Sehu Mujammil A, your answer worked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem by:

```
 var now = new Date(new Date().toUTCString());
 const db = collection(fireStore, 'jobs_col');
 return await getDocs(query(db, where('expire_date', '>=', now)));
```